# Dependency which is missing, however package not broken?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies, synaptic

### The context

I wanted to audit my installed packages. I created a Python helper invoking `dpkg-query`, to create a packages database using Python dictionary and lists. The helper is smart enough to check dependencies are indeed present in the dictionary cloning the installed packages database. I get an error with the `wings3d` package: the helper notified me a package named `erlang-abi-13.a` is missing. Synaptic tells me this package is not installed. It still list this package as a `wings3d` dependency, but displays it in dependency, using italic instead of regular font.

### The question(s)

What does it mean when Synaptic displays a dependency using italic? How a dependency may be missing while the package seems not to be broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All packages starting with `erlang-abi`, are virtual packages. This will be apparent from the apt-cache output:

```
apt-cache show erlang-abi-15.b
N: Can't select versions from package 'erlang-abi-15.b' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

Your helper is not accounting for virtual packages so it fails. This is also why Synaptic shows the packages with *italics*.

Comment: I accepted your answer, although it did not directly answered the initial question. Starting from the useful track you provided, I figured it all, and updated the initial post to add the effective answer. Feel free to review it if you wish.

Comment: @Hibou57 reading your *question* section, you ask "Why the italics" and "Why it shows broken while it isn't". If you are going to answer your (other) question, please write a new question since it doesn't fit the Q&A.

Comment: OK, I've made another edit. Hope this one better preserve the Q&A style.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
apt-cache depends erlang-abi-13.a # see what depends upon it
```

and

```
apt-cache rdepends erlang-abi-13.a # see what it depends upon
```

Then do the same of wings3d. to see if erlang-abi-13.a is listed.

Packages and requirements can get a bit mixed up when you do a Distribution updates. That might be the cause of this.